# Concatenate lines given by grep -A

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file containing multiple sections of the form

```
...
some lines
...
LABEL:  123    234    345
        234    345    456
        345    456    567
...
more lines
...
LABEL:  001    002    003
        004    005    006
        007    008    009
...
more lines
...
```

If I do `grep -A2 LABEL file` I get something like

```
LABEL:  123    234    345
        234    345    456
        345    456    567
LABEL:  001    002    003
        004    005    006
        007    008    009
LABEL:  111    222    333
        444    555    666
        777    888    999
```

but what I want is

```
LABEL:  123    234    345    234    345    456    345    456    567
LABEL:  001    002    003    004    005    006    007    008    009
LABEL:  111    222    333    444    555    666    777    888    999
```

How can I do this with bash? I tried `grep LABEL -A2 file | tr '\n' ' '`, but this removes all newlines, not just the ones inside the grep section.

Comment: What does your input file look like? I might have an `awk` based solution. However, `grep|awk` is a redundancy. `awk '/^LABEL/{a=$0; getline b; getline c; print a b c}' input_file
`

Comment: At least in some variants of grep you will get a line containing `--` between the blocks.

Comment: That's true. Actually the output contains `--` between each block, but those I can delete later. My main problem is how can I print each block in a single line.

Comment: You could have changed your command into `grep LABEL -A2  | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/-- LABEL/\nLABEL/g'`, but the selected answer is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some like this:

```
awk ' /LABEL/ {f=3} f-->0 {printf "%s ",$0} f==0 {print ""}' file
LABEL:  123    234    345         234    345    456         345    456    567
LABEL:  001    002    003         004    005    006         007    008    009
```

Some better output formatting.

```
awk ' /LABEL/ {f=3} f-->0 {$1=$1;printf "%s ",$0} f==0 {print ""}' file
LABEL: 123 234 345 234 345 456 345 456 567
LABEL: 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009
```

And with TAB

```
awk ' /LABEL/ {f=3} f-->0 {$1=$1;printf "%s\t",$0} f==0 {print ""}' OFS="\t" file
LABEL:  123     234     345     234     345     456     345     456     567
LABEL:  001     002     003     004     005     006     007     008     009
```

Comment: A mildly cleaner version is `awk '/LABEL/{f=3} f-->0 {printf "%s%s",$0,(f?OFS:ORS)}' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep LABEL -A2 file  | tr -d '\n' | sed -e "s/\(LABEL:\)/\\n\1/g; s/  */    /g"
```

- First get rid of the newlines with tr,
- then just add a sed command afterwards to replace "LABEL:" with a newline and LABEL:
- finally, the `"s/  */    /g"` part replaces multiple spaces with 4 spaces to get a more
  beautiful look.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It does not append a new line character after the last line and it does not handle the `--` separators from grep. Also, you are duplicating the functionality of sed, twice ;-)

Comment: I did give -1 since this is a cocktail of tools used to solve some that could be done by one.

Answer (score 0):

There are oh so many ways to do it, here is one with sed:

```
sed -n "/^LABEL/ { N; N; s/\n/\t/g ; p }" filename
```

Explanation:

- `-n` means "don't print the output automatically"
- `/^LABEL/`: search for label
- { ... }: command block
- `N; N;` take two lines, append them to the pattern space
- `s/\n/\t/g`: substitute the new lines by tabs in the pattern space
- `p`: print out the pattern space
- `filename` name of your file.